# Swift array element address

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdata

This is a practical question, i'm sending a file by breaking it into trunks of, say, 1000 bytes

```
data = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path)
var dataPackage : [Byte](count: 1000, repeatedValue: 0)

for offset = 0; offset < data.length; {
     // omit some range check here
     data.getBytes(&dataPackage, NSRange(location: offset, length: 1000))
     send(dataPackage)
}
```

Everything was great, until I want to insert a sequence number into dataPackage, at position 0, so naturally, I would change the above to

```
data.getBytes(&dataPackage[1], NSRange(location: offset, length: 999))
```

It turned out that only 1 single element is copied to dataPackage. The rest 999 elements were copied to dont-know-where

My question is, 1) how to make this work, and 2) how array in swift is addressed, in such a way that &data[i] = &data + i (as shown in the 1st example) but &data[i+k] != &data[i] + k

Edit: I solved (1) by doing

```
data.getBytes(&dataPackage + 1, NSRange(location: offset, length: 999))
```

Question (2) remains

Answer (score 4):

Do not `getBytes(&dataPackage[i] + k, ..)`, I think, this may causes "access violation"

Consider this code:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var _val = [Int](count: 1000, repeatedValue: 0);
    subscript(idx:Int) -> Int {
        get {
            println("get: [\(idx)] -> val(\(_val[idx]))")
            return _val[idx]
        }
        set(val) {
            println("set: [\(idx)] old(\(_val[idx])) -> new(\(val))")
            _val[idx] = val
        }
    }
}

func myFunc(ptr:UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>, val:Int) {
    println("mutating: ptr(\(ptr)) <- \(val)")
    ptr.memory = val
}
```

`MyStruct` is just a wrapper around `Array`.

`myFunc` receives a mutable pointer and mutates the value of it.

With this, when yo do:

```
var foo = MyStruct()
myFunc(&foo[1], 12)
```

outputs:

```
get: [1] -> val(0)
mutating: ptr(0x00007fff561619d8) <- 12
set: [1] old(0) -> new(12)
```

See?

1. **Copy** the value to `somewhere`
2. **Mutate** the value of `somewhere`
3. **Write-back** from `somewhere`

I don't know where `somewhere` is, though.

When you do like:

```
var foo = MyStruct()
myFunc(&foo[1] + 1, 12)
```

outputs:

```
get: [1] -> val(0)
set: [1] old(0) -> new(0)
mutating: ptr(0x00007fff5c0b79e0) <- 12
```

This time, my guess would be:

1. **Copy** the value to `somewhere`
2. let `corrupted` as `somewhere + 1`
3. **Write-back** with *unmutated value* from `somewhere`
4. Discard `somewhere`
5. **Mutate** the value of `corrupted`

On the other hand, when you do:

```
var foo = [Int](count:1000, repeatedValue:0)
myFunc(&foo + 1, 12)
```

This means:

1. let `ptr` as the pointer of the first element of `foo`
2. let `ptr` as `ptr + 1`
3. **Mutate** the value of `ptr`

As a result, `foo[1]` will be `12` successfully as you did.

Actually in-out(`&`) of `Array` is very special as mentioned in [the document.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_16)

> When a function is declared as taking an UnsafeMutablePointer argument, it can accept any of the following:
>
> - nil, which is passed as a null pointer
> - An UnsafeMutablePointer value
> - An in-out expression whose operand is a stored lvalue of type Type, which is passed as the address of the lvalue
> - An in-out [Type] value, which is passed as a pointer to the start of the array, and lifetime-extended for the duration of the call

Only the built-in `Array` has the last feature.

So, when you pass `&notAnArrayLvalue`(including `&array[i]`) to `UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>` parameter, the length should be always `1`, and you should not `+` or `-` it.

Comment: Excellent explanation. To me it seems like Swift's approach trying to "help" people with accessing memory (and that's somehow unavoidable) it does a bad service and hurts more than it helps.