# Does array element dereferencing and addressing - &buffer[index] - work in Swift?

Tags: c, swift, pointers

I am writing a Swift application for which I need to use C functions for some network buffering from sockets. Swift imports these functions via a bridging header and they require a buffer pointer parameter.

The two functions are effectively:

```
read(Socket s, void *buf, int num);
write(Socket s, const void *buf, int num);
```

The Swift compiler indicates that it these functions require an `UnsafePointer<Void>`. I have some `[UInt8]` types that hold my writeable data and accept my readable data. The Swift compiler does not complain with what I have written, however I believe the following code is not doing what I would expect it to in C syntax.

This is my read loop:

```
var index: Int32 = 0    
while index < length {
    var toRead = length - index
    if toRead > bufferSize {
        toRead = bufferSize
    }

    // Read into my buffer ([Int8]), starting at element `hasRead`
    let justRead: Int32 = read(s, &buffer[Int(index)], toRead)
    index += justRead
}
```

And my write loop:

```
var index: Int32 = 0
while index < length {
    var toWrite: Int32 = length - index
    if toWrite > bufferSize {
        toWrite = bufferSize
    }

    // Write from my buffer ([Int8]), starting at element `index`
    let wrote = write(s, &buffer[Int(index)], toWrite)
    index += wrote
}
```

My question is: Is `&buffer[Int(index)]` the correct way to pass a (mutable) array in this situation? (I.e. is it doing what I would expect C to do with that syntax - taking the address of the index'th element of array bytes). And if not, how do I appropriately pass my `[UInt8]` to the bridged C function?

Comment: A similar problem (with computed properties instead of subscripting) is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232190/swift-2-0-inout-function-parameters-and-computed-properties. I assume that the same reasoning is valid here, and your code should work as expected.

Comment: @MartinR The concept is valid, but I don't think it's safe to assume that the passed-in pointer can be used to access any values in the array besides the one it points to.

Comment: @jtbandes: You are right. I had misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend being careful with `&buffer[Int(index)]`. It's unclear what it's guaranteed to do from the docs. Certainly, it can be used to modify a single element of the array, but I don't think you should rely on pointer arithmetic with this pointer (so you shouldn't pass it into a function like that).

What you can/should use, however, is [`withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer()` (apparently missing from docs currently)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structm/Array/s:FSa30withUnsafeMutableBufferPointeru__rFRGSaq__FzFzRGVSs26UnsafeMutableBufferPointerq__qd__qd__) (or the non-mutable version). This guarantees to call the provided closure with an UnsafeMutableBufferPointer to contiguous storage that you can use to read from and write to the array. You'll probably want to use its `baseAddress`.

(Also note that Swift has a [ContiguousArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ContiguousArray_Structure/index.html) in addition to Array, whose storage is guaranteed to be contiguous, so you might see slightly better performance than Array since you know you'll ask it for a contiguous buffer anyway. But don't make too many assumptions about performance here — it's not very well documented! I doubt you'd need to use ContiguousArray in practice.)

Comment: Last time I checked, array indexing works with pass-by-inout in the following manner. The compiler retrieves the element from the indexed collection into a temporary object using the indexing getter. The address of the temporary object is then passed to the callee. After the callee returns, the indexing setter is invoked on the collection with the – now potentially modified – temporary.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what I've seen as well. This also means `didSet`s (and I guess `set`s) will be called whether or not the callee modifies the value. Pointer arithmetic on `&buf[0]` did seem to work in a simple test, but I don't think it's guaranteed to work in every case (probably undefined behavior).

Comment: [This page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) also has some helpful info.

Comment: If I am to use the `baseAddress` of the pointer accessible from `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer`, I assume I will then need to invoke `advancedBy:` in order to advance the pointer to the correct index... While I understand it completely, the incompleteness of the documentation can be quite a hurdle sometimes!

Comment: @Ephemera you can simply use the + operator (it works on UnsafePointer in Swift).

Answer (score 1):

You could:

```
read(s, &buffer + Int(index), toRead)
```

I think, `&buffer[Int(index)]` is not safe, as discussed in [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26418461/3804019)